# HackerRank won't accept my code for the Set .discard(), .remove() & .pop() challenge

Tags: python, set

Here's the prompt:
You have a non-empty set s, and you have to execute N commands given in N lines.
The commands will be pop, remove and discard.

Input Format:

- The first line contains integer n, the number of elements in the set s.
- The second line contains n space separated elements of set s. All of the elements are non-negative integers, less than or equal to 9.
- The third line contains integer N, the number of commands.
- The next N lines contains either pop, remove and/or discard commands followed by their associated value.

Issue: The output within HackerRank differs from the output in an external IDE.

My Solution:

```
input()
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
num_commands = int(input())
command = ["", ""]
for i in range(num_commands):
    command = input().split()
    if len(command) == 1:
        getattr(s, command[0])()
    elif len(command) == 2:
        command[1] = int(command[1])
        if command[1] in s:
            getattr(s, command[0])(command[1])
print(sum(s))
```

Test input:

```
9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10
pop
remove 9
discard 9
discard 8
remove 7
pop
discard 6
remove 5
pop
discard 5
```

Issue:
It says my output is 6 and the expected output is 4. When I test the code in my IDE, the output is 4. I could just look up a different solution but usually it is more helpful for me to understand where I went wrong because clearly there's a gap in my understanding. ChatGPT didn't know what to do either. What is going wrong? Thanks a ton!

Comment: What are each of those commands supposed to do?

Comment: Python sets aren't ordered, so `pop()` removes a random element. I don't see how you can expect a consistent result if this is used.

Comment: And the only difference between `remove()` and `discard()` is whether it raises an exception of the element isn't found, but your code checks whether the element is in the set. What's the point of having two different commands if you make them do the same thing?

Comment: For clarity of the problem, can you include the link to the problem here?

Comment: Just read the discussion to that problem on hacker rank. Nothing is wrong with your understandig. `pop` will remove an arbitrary element. This cannot give you a consistent result.

Comment: @Barmar - 1st command is irrelevant because sets can be any length in python. 2nd command is the set s to be manipulated, 3rd command is the number of commands to follow. pop() does remove a random element which is why I included the if statement: if command[1] in s. This prevents a key error if the user tries use the remove() on a number that isn't in the set. There is no point to having both remove() and discard(), but I have to include both because this is for a coding challenge question which requires it, Thank you :)

Comment: @Daniel Hao https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-set-discard-remove-pop/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: I meant what are "pop", "remove", and "discard" supposed to do to the set, not what each input line means.

Comment: @MSpiller Will do, didn't know that was there, thank you. pop() does remove a random element but I have to include it because the prompt requires it, that's why I included the if statement: if command[i] in s

Comment: @Barmar pop, remove and discard are supposed to call the corresponding functions pop() remove(i) and discard(i) on the set that the user specified.

Comment: @Barmar OH! I just got it, you are correct there is no way to expect consistent results because of the pop() method. In cpython pop() removes the last element and in pypy, pop() removes the first element. This describes the discrepancy between my IDE and HackerRank. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way to predict with certainty which element is going to be removed and the final sum becomes dependent on the python implementation:

pypy3 chooses to remove the last element

python3 chooses to remove the first element

With the test case a correct solution will output 4 with python and 6 with pypy

Reverse the set to conform to python's pop() implementation:

```
input()
s  = list(map(int, input().split()))
s.reverse()
s = set(s)
num_commands = int(input())
command = ["", ""]
for i in range(num_commands):
    command = input().split()
    if len(command) == 1:
        getattr(s, command[0])()
    elif len(command) == 2:
        command[1] = int(command[1])
        if command[1] in s:
            getattr(s, command[0])(command[1])
print(sum(s))
```